# Android: Как скрывать баннер AdMod-а если нет подключения?

Tags: android, admob

XML разметка:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/gggg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3725575433315376/6681731334" />
```

Подключение в активити:

```
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.gggg);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Если пользователь не подключен к сети, то вместо баннера пустое пространство размером с баннер.
Как показать баннер только после его загрузки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не поверите, но ответ содержится в официальной документации: [`com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener`](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#play-adlistener).

Comment: Два дня смотрел на эту страницу...
Спасибо что носом ткнули.

Comment: Сделал так:
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
           @Override
           public void onAdLoaded() {    
            adView.setVisibility(0);
           }
         });

Comment: А почему вы используете 0 вместо константы `View.VISIBLE`? Ведь во втором случае код получается читабельнее и проще для восприятия.

Comment: Верно. Спасибо.